# Stack and Hash joint

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, stack

I'm trying to write a data structure which is a combination of Stack and HashSet with fast push/pop/membership (I'm looking for constant time operations). Think of Python's OrderedDict.

I tried a few things and I came up with the following code: [HashInt](http://github.com/brtzsnr/structure/blob/master/src/main/java/ibis/structure/HashInt.java) and [SetInt](http://github.com/brtzsnr/structure/blob/master/src/main/java/ibis/structure/SetInt.java). I need to add some documentation to the source, but basically I use a hash with linear probing to store indices in a vector of the keys. Since linear probing always puts the last element at the end of a continuous range of already filled cells, pop() can be implemented very easy without a sophisticated remove operation.

I have the following problems:

- the data structure consumes a lot of memory (some improvement is obvious: `stackKeys` is larger than needed).
- some operations are slower than if I have used fastutil (eg: pop(), even push() in some scenarios). I tried rewriting the classes using fastutil and trove4j, but the overall speed of my application halved.

What performance improvements would you suggest for my code?
What open-source library/code do you know that I can try?

Comment: Admit it, you just wanted to use hash and joint in the same sentence ;-)

Comment: Isn't there a class in the standard API that meets your requirements - maybe `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap`?

Comment: "natural ordering of its keys". `ConcurrentSkipListMap` doesn't keep the insertion order. But I'm looking into `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Alexandru are you trying to achieve a stack with a fast contains() and uniqueness or just a fast contains() ?

Comment: both: fast uniqueness and fast contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got a pretty good implementation.  The only improvement obvious to me is that you do more work than you need to by searching when popping.  You should store in the stack not the key itself but *the index into the key array*.  This gives you trivially fast pops at the expense of only one more pointer indirection when you want to peek the last item.

Just size your stack to LOAD_FACTOR*(heap array size), in addition to that, and you should have about as fast an implementation as you could expect with as little memory as you can manage given your speed requirements.

Comment: This kind of trick I was hoping for. I think storing the index in the `stackKey` array will speedup the pop() function a lot. I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: It works great: from initial tests has() improved 2x, pop() improved 4x, push() improved only slightly. The biggest gain was from the removed redirection in the search().

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is (almost) already available in the libraries: LinkedHashSet is a hash-set with an underlying doubly linked list (which makes it iterable). LinkedHashMap even has a removeEldestEntry which sounds very similar to a pop-method.

How is the performance of a naive solution like:

`class HashStack<T> {`

```
    private HashMap<T, Integer> counts = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    private Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();

    public void push(T t) {
        stack.push(t);
        counts.put(t, 1 + getCount(t));
    }

    public T pop() {
        T t = stack.pop();
        counts.put(t, counts.get(t) - 1);
        return t;
    }

    private int getCount(T t) {
        return counts.containsKey(t) ? counts.get(t) : 0;
    }

    public boolean contains(T t) {
        return getCount(t) > 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return stack.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but I already implemented a similar solution with fastutil which may be faster because fastutil uses primitives. I'm looking more for a combination of HashTables and Stack which uses a single table if possible. Right now my memory requirements are about 3x the size of keys inserted and what I have is not cache aware since I'm always looking in two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [TreeSet<T>](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) as it provides guaranteed O(log n) cost for add, remove, and contains.

Comment: but this should be doable with amortized constant time, no?